# How to extract all the frames from a video?

Tags: python, opencv, moviepy

Hey so I wanted to know how I can extract all frames from a vide using MoviePy
Currently I am doing it in open-cv which is really really slow. My current code :-

```
vidObj = cv2.VideoCapture("./video.mp4")
count = 0
flag = 1
while flag:
    flag, image = vidObj.read()
    try:
        cv2.imwrite(f"./images/frame{count}.jpg", image)
    except:
        break
    count += 1
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve the same in MoviePy please?

Comment: please explain what information you need that hasn't been provided by https://moviepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: "it" is slow? what part of it is slow? and what's slow in objective numbers? are you dissatisfied with the speed of writing jpegs? because reading the video is certainly going as fast as it can, because it's using ffmpeg as a backend.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `write_images_sequence()` method.

`%05d` represents a 5 digit frame index.

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

video = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
video.write_images_sequence('frame%05d.png', logger='bar')
```